# Generating multiple Access PDFs from a large report based on a field

Tags: ms-access, pdf, report

I have a very large Access Report that I'd like to file as separate PDFs (stored in the same folder on a C drive)based on a field called Security Contact. I want to name each PDF based on the name of the security contact. Any ideas? I am using Access 2013. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can export to PDF via the `DoCmd.OutputTo` method.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReport", acFormatPDF, "C:\MyReport.pdf"
```

However, this method doesn't allow passing a filter, so to output each security contact separately, you will need to have the report obtain the correct security contact and filter itself. There are various ways to do this programmatically. Options include storing the value in a table and referencing that table in the report's query. Another is to refer to an open form's field (perhaps a hidden one) in the report's query.

For example, your report's query might be:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE SecurityContact=[Forms]![frmRunSecConReport]![txtContact]
```

This causes the report to be based on records for that specific value of `SecurityContact`.

The steps would be:

- Loop through the possible Security Contact values (by opening and moving through an appropriate recordset containing their distinct values).
- For each value of Security Contact:

  - Set the reference field (in a table or on a form as described above) so that running the report will only include that Security Contact,
  - Call `OutputTo` with a filename generated from the value of Security Contact.

Note that if you want to avoid the warning message box asking if you want to overwrite existing files, you will need to delete existing ones first (refer to the `Kill` statement in VBA).